# Qt5.5.1 crosscompile for arm board: make mistake

Tags: qt, ubuntu, arm

These days, I want to build Qt environment on my arm board, but I have encountered some problems.The details are as following.
  First , I crosscompile tslib:

```
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk$ sudo tar -zvxf tslib-1.4.tar.gz
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk$ cd tslib
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/tslib$ ./autogen.sh 
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/tslib$ ./configure --host=arm-linux --prefix=/home/newdisk/optnew/tslib ac_cv_func_malloc_0_nonnull=yes
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/tslib$ make 
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/tslib$ sudo make install
```

Next, I crosscompile Qt src code:

a. new autoconfig.sh

```
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1$ sudo vi autoconfig.sh

#autoconfig.sh
#!/bin/sh
./configure \
-v \
-prefix /home/newdisk/optnew/qt5.5.1 \
-release \
-opensource \
-make libs \
-xplatform linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ \
-optimized-qmake \
-pch \
-qreal float \
-qt-sql-sqlite \
-qt-libjpeg \
-qt-zlib \
-no-opengl \
-no-iconv \
-nomake examples \
-nomake tools \
-nomake tests \
-skip qt3d \
-skip qtcanvas3d \
-I/home/newdisk/optnew/tslib/include \
-L/home/newdisk/optnew/tslib/lib

exit
```

b. edit the qmake.conf in qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0/qtbase/mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++/qmake.conf

```
 lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1/qtbase/mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++$ sudo vi qmake.conf

 #qmake.conf
 #
 # qmake configuration for building with arm-linux-gnueabi-g++
 #

 MAKEFILE_GENERATOR      = UNIX
 CONFIG                 += incremental 
 QMAKE_INCREMENTAL_STYLE = sublib

 QT_QPA_DEFAULT_PLATFORM = linuxfb #eglfs
 QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += -O2 -march=armv6
 QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -O2 -march=armv6

 include(../common/linux.conf)
 include(../common/gcc-base-unix.conf)
 include(../common/g++-unix.conf)

 # modifications to g++.conf
 QMAKE_CC                = /home/newdisk/optnew/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
 QMAKE_CXX               = /home/newdisk/optnew/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++
 QMAKE_LINK              = /home/newdisk/optnew/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++
 QMAKE_LINK_SHLIB        = /home/newdisk/optnew/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++

 # modifications to linux.conf
 QMAKE_AR                = /home/newdisk/optnew/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ar cqs
 QMAKE_OBJCOPY           = /home/newdisk/optnew/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-objcopy
 QMAKE_NM                = /home/newdisk/optnew/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-nm -P
 QMAKE_STRIP             = /home/newdisk/optnew/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-strip
 load(qt_config)
```

c. then I run autoconfig.sh,

```
 lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1$ sudo ./autoconfig.sh
```

but after I run make, I get some errors,

```
 lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1$ sudo make

 ../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qvector.h:380:12: warning:    assuming signed overflow does not occur when assuming that (X + c) < X is always false
 /home/newdisk/optnew/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -include .pch/Qt5Gui -pipe -march=armv6 -march=armv6 -O3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -std=c++0x -fno-exceptions -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_MTDEV -DQT_NO_LIBUDEV -DQT_NO_LIBINPUT -DQT_NO_USING_NAMESPACE -DQT_BUILD_GUI_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x050000 -DQT_ENABLE_HARFBUZZ_NG -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I/home/newdisk/optnew/tslib/include -I../../include -I../../include/QtGui -I../../include/QtGui/5.5.1 -I../../include/QtGui/5.5.1/QtGui -I../3rdparty/harfbuzz-ng/include -I../3rdparty/zlib -I../../include/QtCore/5.5.1 -I../../include/QtCore/5.5.1/QtCore -I../../include/QtCore -I.moc -I../../mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -o .obj/qpdf.o painting/qpdf.cpp
 painting/qpdf.cpp: In member function 'int QPdfEnginePrivate::generateRadialGradientShader(const QRadialGradient*, const QTransform&, bool)':
 painting/qpdf.cpp:2157:44: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' in '((QPdf::ByteStream*)((QPdf::ByteStream*)((QPdf::ByteStream*)((QPdf::ByteStream*)s.QPdf::ByteStream::operator<<(((const char*)"<<\012/ShadingType 3\012/ColorSpace ")))->QPdf::ByteStream::operator<<((alpha ? ((const char*)"/DeviceGray\012") : ((const char*)"/DeviceRGB\012"))))->QPdf::ByteStream::operator<<(((const char*)"/AntiAlias true\012/Domain [0 1]\012/Coords [")))->QPdf::ByteStream::operator<<(p0.QPointF::x()))->QPdf::ByteStream::operator<<(p0.QPointF::y()) << r0'
 painting/qpdf.cpp:180:17: note: candidates are: QPdf::ByteStream& QPdf::ByteStream::operator<<(char)
 painting/qpdf.cpp:218:17: note:                 QPdf::ByteStream& QPdf::ByteStream::operator<<(qreal)
 painting/qpdf.cpp:225:17: note:                 QPdf::ByteStream& QPdf::ByteStream::operator<<(int)
 In file included from ../../include/QtCore/qbytearray.h:1:0,
                  from ../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qstring.h:42,
                  from ../../include/QtCore/qstring.h:1,
                  from ../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qcoreapplication.h:38,
                  from ../../include/QtCore/qcoreapplication.h:1,
                  from kernel/qt_gui_pch.h:53:
 ./../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qbytearray.h: In member function 'void QPdfEnginePrivate::xprintf(const char*, ...)':
 ../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qbytearray.h:98:19: note: the mangling of 'va_list' has changed in GCC 4.4
 make[3]: *** [.obj/qpdf.o] Error 1
 make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/newdisk/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1/qtbase/src/gui'
 make[2]: *** [sub-gui-make_first] Error 2
 make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/newdisk/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1/qtbase/src'
 make[1]: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
 make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/newdisk/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1/qtbase'
 make: *** [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
```

Could you please tell me how to eliminate these errors? I am using Qt5.5.1 and ubuntu 14.04, and my arm board is armv6 architecture!

In addition, the line 2157 and the relative lines in painting/qpdf.cpp are as following:

```
int function = createShadingFunction(gradient, from, to, reflect, alpha);

QByteArray shader;
QPdf::ByteStream s(&shader);
s << "<<\n"
    "/ShadingType 3\n"
    "/ColorSpace " << (alpha ? "/DeviceGray\n" : "/DeviceRGB\n") <<
    "/AntiAlias true\n"
    "/Domain [0 1]\n"
    "/Coords [" << p0.x() << p0.y() << r0 << p1.x() << p1.y() << r1 << "]\n"//2157 line
    "/Extend [true true]\n"
    "/Function " << function << "0 R\n"
    ">>\n"
    "endobj\n";
int shaderObject = addXrefEntry(-1);
write(shader);
return shaderObject;
```

Comment: Nothing about architecture etc. but the stream operator is defined twice for the same set of arguments. Find out why and how can you fix that. The info is in error message.

Comment: I have added some error details in the relative file `painting/qpdf.cpp`,Could you see my question again?@AlexanderVX

Comment: Try to break apart: s << one; s << two; s << three; and then try to comment out one by one. And then try to make a type cast for the ambiguous argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relative file is the qt source codes. There are some explanations on qt official website:

`typedef qreal
 Typedef for double unless Qt is configured with the -qreal float option.`

The reason I infer is that when ran `make` with the parameter `-qreal float`, error: `ambiguous overload for 'operator<<'` occurred.

Finally, I edited the file `autoconfig.sh` without `-qreal float` and ran make again,there is no error!